# Paging And Sorting queries in Spring Data Cassandra

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

As per the Spring-data-cassandra docs,
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#requirements

Paging and Sorting queries are supported, however, when I use Interface PagingAndSortingRepository, paginated queries throws following exception:

Below is my interface definition:

```
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String>
```

.
.
.

Below is stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: neither slice nor page queries are supported yet
 at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryMethod.verify(CassandraQueryMethod.java:80)
 at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryMethod.<init>(CassandraQueryMethod.java:68)
 at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.CassandraRepositoryFactory$CassandraQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(CassandraRepositoryFactory.java:106)
 at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357)
 at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:192)
 at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
 at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
 at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean.java:62)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
 ... 11 more
```

Please help !!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a documentation copy/paste error.  Please enter a JIRA issue for the incorrect documentation.  There is already an issue tracking whether paging & sorting can be supported at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-56

Comment: seems like its not implemented for Cassandra.

Comment: Um, that's basically what I said.